# Swift how to wait for a Async function to complete

Tags: swift, cllocation

My dilemma: I will in dice this in my code below, but my plan for my code is too show items based on location. When the user loads the app it should show all the items around them. My issue is in my view did load i call the startupdatinglocation followed by the function to find my items. However my function to find my items requires a location from the user, so every time it runs the location is nil. Is there a way that i can wait till a location is found then do the function?

Notes
- i have tried putting the find item function in the didupdatelocation, but that does not load the items when the user loads the app. it just leaves it blank

```
var locManager = CLLocationManager()

var geocoder = CLGeocoder()

var placemarkLongitude = CLLocationDegrees()

var placemarkLatitude = CLLocationDegrees()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // check if locations eabled
     print("I got here 1")
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        self.locManager.delegate = self
        self.locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        print("I got here 2")
    }
    else {
        print ("Locations not enabled")
    }

    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to Refresh")
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: "findItems", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    self.tableView.addSubview(refresher)

    findItems()

}

func locManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    print("Started Updating Location!")
    let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0]
    _ = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
    _ = userLocation.coordinate.longitude
    print(locations)

}
```

Comment: Moving the code into `didUpdateLocations` is the right way. Maybe you have to reload the table view at a certain point after `findItems()`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I usually do when I need to locate the user first and then perform an action (update UI/Call web service/etc).

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MKUserLocation) {

    //userLocated is a private bool property that will start on false (private let userLocated = false)
    if !userLocated {

        //Update the map region to center on the user with 0.02 span
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude), span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.02, 0.02))
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        //Set the property to true as we already have a location for our user
        userLocated = true

        //Call Network API or do what you need here
        NetworkManager.sharedInstance.getItemsNerby(userLocation) //you can add a completion handler to then updateUI or do what you need with those items.
    }
}
```